# Execute raw update query in Room Database

Tags: android-room

I have a Room database where I want to run a basic `UPDATE Table SET Column = ? WHERE Column2 = ?`.

I can execute my query like so

```
val db = ... /// my room database

val sqlDb = db.openHelper.writableDatabase
sqlDb.execSQL(query.toString(), arrayOf(valueFor1, valueFor2))
```

However this didn't sit so great with me as I am not clear on whether I am meant to close the `sqlDb` after each query or I can leave it and let Room re-use it, as well as this feels like dropping down to lower-level API.

I tried using Room's own query method like so:

```
db
.query(SimpleSQLiteQuery(query.toString(), arrayOf(valueFor1, valueFor2)))
.close()
```

However, no update happens to the data in my db.

Is there any way for me to execute this query from `RoomDatabase` object directly?

**Note**: I do NOT want to use DAO at all. My query is dynamically created by inspecting columns in the db and I have about 100 tables in my database, I don't want to have to add this to every DAO.

Answer (score 0):

In an @Dao annotated interface have a function:-

```
@Query("UPDATE Table SET Column=:newValue WHERE Column2=existingValue")
fun myUpdate(existingValue: String, newValue: String)
```

In the @Database annotated class you define an abstract function to get the @Dao annotated class. Which allows you to then get the Dao interface/abstract class and use the functions.

Then you would use something like:-

```
val db = ... /// my room database
val dao = getTheDao()
dao.myUpdate("OLD","NEW")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all. My query is created dynamically by first running `PRAGMA table_info("table_name");` and then parsing columns; and I have about 100 tables in sqlite. I want to avoid DAO altogether.